# R: efficient way to loop rbind for multiple files

Tags: r

I have 1000 permutations saved as RData objects. I want to combine the `info` object from all of these permutations into a single table (`info_perm`). This is very fast to start with, but ends up becoming much slower as the file size increases. Any suggestions about how to solve this problem more efficiently rather than rewriting `info_perm` each time? Thanks!

```
info_perm <- NULL; for (perm in 1:1000) {
  load(paste0("./output/", perm, ".RData"))
  info$perm <- perm
  rbind(info_perm, info) -> info_perm
  if (perm/100 == round(perm/100)) {print(perm)}
}; rm(perm)
```

*note: I'm aware of options like `do.call("rbind",l)` which would work if I had all of my files in the environment at the same time, but is there a faster way to do it in this framework rather than saving intermediary version of `info` after each is read in?*

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). for each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: I commented that even though you say you are aware of options like that ... the fact that you know about those options and choose to not use them indicates either misattribution of the bottleneck in your process or providing a red-herring to us.

Comment: I suggest that using `load(.)` in a loop like that is at some point going to bite you: it writes all of its contents' objects to the current environment. If you are certain that they all have exactly the one thing you need, or if you know that your current environment is otherwise austere with nothing at all valuable in it, then you may be okay. Otherwise, if you load in an `.rda` file that overwrites another variable that you might be using, you will never know this until something else (unrelated) breaks. I suggest `e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv()); load(..., envir=e); e$info$perm <- perm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about futures?

```
library(future)
library(future.apply)

plan(multisession)

perm = 1:1000 
info_perm <- do.call(rbind, future_lapply(perm, function(perm){
  load(paste0("./output/", perm, ".RData"))
  info$perm <- perm
  if (perm/100 == round(perm/100)) {print(perm)}
  info
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for -- a way to not need to have the hundreds of intermediate info files open at once to be called by rbind